# Find a model with empty association in Gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have an model with a [BelongsTo](https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html) association. My goal is to find all `Foos` with an empty association, i.e. no `Bar` is set. So far I have not found a [method](https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Association-Mode).

```golang
type Foo struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name    string
    BarID   uint
    Bar     Bar
}
```

Do I have to manually check if the field `barid` is 0? This sounds incorrect.

```golang
foo := Foo{}
result := r.db.Where(Foo{Name: "Test", BarID: 0}).First(&foo)
```

Comment: Yes, you have to "manually" check if barID is `0` or `nil`, I think `nil` is a solution you are looking for. I am just wondering. How would you even "not manually" check that?

Comment: @rosmak: I would have assumed that there is a convenience method like "AssociationEmpty". The reason is that I'm not aware of the internal and don't know if 0 is used for a missing reference or -1. It would be even possible to use a different type for the foreign key column like a string, hence a method aware of this and handling the details would be nice to have. nil would not work, since uint is a basic type and not an interface.

Comment: I think this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66563805/how-to-insert-a-null-foreign-key-in-gorm

Comment: @BenoîtZu I tried this, but I also have to search for the BarID later. How would I search for a BarID with value e.g. 3 then? Passing a pointer to 3 would not work I guess since the pointer address is always different, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around it indeed seems that the value for an empty association is 0, i.e. checking for `BarID: 0` works. Not sure if this value is generated by Gorm or the database. Then it would be database dependent.